# Error when searching parsed webpage with python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am logging into a site, making a search query and then filtering the results with beautifulsoup to get all the terms in the "b" tag. From the results I'd like to check whether the search term (Testing) is present. My current code is below. The problem I am having is that even when there is a result and the term is present I still get a not present response. I have printed the filtered query and read through it and the result is definitely there so the error is in the searching part. I think the problem is that in the html the word testing isn't by itself so its Testing.example or Testing.test and so the search can't find it by it self surrounded by spaces. How do I search for a word/phrase within a longer word/phrase.

I need "Testing" to be found in "example.Testing.example" or in "test.Testing.example"

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

```
words = ["Testing"]
br.open ('http://www.example.com/browse.php?psec=2&search=%s' % words)
html = br.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
filtered = soup.findAll('b')

# print filtered

for word in words:
    if word in filtered:
        print "%s found." % word
    else:
        print "%s not found." % word
```

Edit

```
[<b><a title="Unknown">---</a></b>, <b>Welcome Back<br /><a href="/user/"><
span style="color:#0080FF;"></span></a>!<br /></b>, <b><span class="smallfo
nt"><a href="/messages.php?action=viewmailbox"><img height="14px" style="border:
none" alt="inbox" title="inbox (no new messages)" src="/pic/pn_inbox.gif" /></a>
59 (0 New)</span></b>, <b><span class="smallfont">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/message
s.php?action=viewmailbox&amp;box=-1"><img height="14px" style="border:none" alt=
"sentbox" title="sentbox" src="/pic/pn_sentbox.gif" /></a> 37</span></b>, <b>Sho
w all</b>, <b><< Prev</b>, <b>Next >></b>, <b>1&nbsp;-&nbsp;7</b>, **<b>The.Testing
.example.T3Z6.L</b>**, <b><span style="color:#FF5500;">dgHn</span
></b>, <b><a href="/details.php?id=15829&amp;hit=1&amp;filelist=1">1</a></b>, <b
><a href="/details.php?id=15829&amp;hit=1&amp;=1"><font>30</font></a></
b>, <b><a href="/details.php?id=15829&amp;hit=1&amp;todlers=1">1</a></b>,
```

When I print filtered I get the above result. Its slightly longer but you get the idea. Five lines from the bottom in **s you see the result that should case a positive but isn't.

Comment: When you print out the value of `filtered` what is it?  It's important to be able to add `print` statements (or functions) to display intermediate results.

Comment: @S.Lott I edited my question and added in the print result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something more like the following

```
words = ["Testing"]
br.open ('http://www.example.com/browse.php?psec=2&search=%s' % words)
html = br.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
filtered = soup.findAll('b')
"""element.contents[0] gives you the  first element inside the <b> tags
If you want some other part of inside the b tag see  
BeatifulSoup documentation at the line below """
filteredcontents = [element.contents[0] for element in filtered]

for word in words:
    if any(word in filteredcontent for filteredcontent in filteredcontents):
        print "%s found." % word
    else:
        print "%s not found." % word
```

BeatifulSoup Documentation is available 
[here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html)

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly and your explanation makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat lector: I'm not into BeautifulSoup details.

`filtered` is a list of `b` elements. You are missing a level. Try this:

```
for word in words:
    for b_elt in filtered:
        if word in b_elt: # or word in b_elt.text or suchlike
            print "%s found." % word
```

Comment: That returns "not found" "found" for each element. So like 11 not founds or however many b elements there are. It still however creates false negatives. I only need it to search overall.

Comment: @Michael: I don't see "not found" anywhere in the 4 lines of code that I provided. Please explain!

Comment: I added a not found to account for the case it isn't found. I solved the issue another way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
filtered = soup.findAll('b')
```

will give you results like`[one, two]`.

You need to compare contents of filtered with words

You can try something like:

```
soup.findAll(text=words)
```